# Vector space of multivariate polynomials in Magma

Tags: magma-cas, multivariate-polynomial

I would like to define the $K$-vector space generated by a finite basis of multivariate polynomials (in $n$ variables, over the field $K$). My goal is then to find out the components of any element in this vector space w.r.t this basis. This is not a Gröbner basis problem since the coefficients are not polynomials. In my application, $K$ is finite.

It is easy to do in the univariate case, but I don't see how to proceed in general. Should I define this space as a subspace of a larger finite dimensional vector space over $K$ (for example, polynomials of some bounded total degree) ?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Absolutely, you should consider it as a subspace of a finite-dimensional space. If you are truly just thinking of them as vectors and do not need to do any polynomial multiplication then you should directly consider them as elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$. It should be easy to set up a homomorphism directly from the polynomial ring to $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ and then build the subspace and compute the dimension in this setting.

Comment: OK, thank you. Here $n$ would be the dimension of the space I want to construct, right (and not really the number of variables) ? And I define such a map by sending the $l$-th basis element of my space to the $l$-th element of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{n}$ ?

Comment: @pb7 yeah, the dimension that you want (for example if you had 2 variables and wanted polynomials of degree 3 or less, you would need 10 dimensional)

Comment: I am able to create formal sets (space of homogeneous polynomials of given degree, then my susbet), but how to convert them to vector spaces in order to compute dimensions, etc. ?

Comment: You just want to put together a list of all monic monomials that are of degree $d$ or less, and define a homomorphism that maps them to the basis of your vector space. Then apply this homomorphism to all of the polynomials in your set to get a set of vectors.